# Prove that any finitely generated submodule of $R^+$ (the field of quotients) is free of rank $1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, modules, principal-ideal-domains

I am working on the following problem:

> Let $R$ be a principal ideal domain and $R^+$ the field of quotients. Then $R^+$ is an $R$-module. Prove that any finitely generated submodule of $R^+$ is a free module of rank $1$.

The idea I tried:

Suppose that $M=\left<\frac{a_1}{b_1},\frac{a_2}{b_2},...,\frac{a_n}{b_n}\right>$ is a finitely generated $R$-submodule of $R^+$. Let's prove that the elements of the basis are not linearly independent for $n>1$. Indeed take the elements $\frac{a_i}{b_i}$ and $\frac{a_j}{b_j}$. Then for $r=b_i a_j$ and $s=a_i b_j$ we have $r\frac{a_i}{b_i}-s\frac{a_j}{b_j}=0$ which means they are not linearly independent. So $M$ is of rank $1$.

The problem I have is that it looks right to me but I did not use in anyway the fact that $R$ is a PID. Can you tell me where does my reasoning fail?

Another thing I tried was that since $R$ is a PID I could use the fact that any $R$-submodule of $R$ is an ideal in $R$ and since $R$ is a PID it follows. But how to connect the dots from the submodule of $R^+$ to the submodule of $R$?

Comment: You need to first prove that the module is in fact free, before your proof makes sense.

Comment: Isn't that obvious by definition? The definition I use is that a module is free if it has a basis.

Comment: Why would it be obvious? Where do you argue that a basis exists?

Comment: OK I see now. The fact that it says it is finitely generated does not mean that it is a basis.

Comment: Yes, precisely. This is where you need that $R$ is a PID (I have not really thought about whether the assumptions can be weakened, but it is at least quite easy with $R$ being a PID assuming you know the structure theorem for finitely generated modules over those).

Comment: Maybe you start with finding the generator of $\langle \frac{2}{3}, \frac{4}{5} \rangle$. The general case is actually not harder than this special case. (By induction, you have do deal with 2 generators only anyway). I dont think one should invoke the structure theorem here, which of course immediately kills the whole exercise.

Comment: I don't know that theorem. I need to solve it with more elementary stuff.

Comment: Ok, so without the classification, the idea will be to use that given some set of elements, you can take a greatest common divisor of them, which allows you to get a generator for the submodule.

Comment: OK, I have the general idea now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $M$ be a *nonzero* finitely generated submodule of $R^+$; you can assume a set of generators is
$$
\left\{\frac{a_1}{d},\frac{a_2}{d},\dots,\frac{a_n}{d}\right\}
$$
by using a common denominator. The $R$-homomorphism $M\to R$ defined by $x\mapsto dx$ is injective, so $M$ is isomorphic to a nonzero ideal of $R$.

(The assumption $M\ne\{0\}$ is of course necessary at the outset.)

---

As already commented, you can't assume $M$ has a basis to begin with.