# Fraction Field and isomorphism of R-modules

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative integral domain and let $F$ be its field of fractions. Consider $F$ as an $R$-module. Suppose that $M < F$ is a finitely generated $R$-submodule of $F$. Then show there exists an ideal $I \unlhd R$ such that $I \cong M$ as $R$-modules. I was thinking suppose that $M = \left\{ \frac{a_{i}}{b_{i}}\right\}$, then maybe there is some isomorphism with $\left\{ a_{i} \right\}$, but I don't think this works.

Comment: For partial answer ( if  R is a pid), https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1834394/prove-that-any-finitely-generated-submodule-of-r-the-field-of-quotients-is

Answer (score 2):

Let $M$ be generated by $\frac{a_1}{b_1},\ldots,\frac{a_n}{b_n}$. Let $b=b_1\cdots b_n$ be the product of the denominators. Then $bM\cong M$, since $R$ is a domain, so multiplying by $b$ is invertible (with inverse $1/b$). Also $bM\subseteq R$, since $$b\frac{a_i}{b_i} = a_i\prod_{j\ne i} b_j \in R,$$
so all of the generators of $bM$ are in $R$. But then $bM$ is an $R$-submodule of $R$, which makes it an ideal of $R$ by definition.

Comment: So then is $M$ isomorphic to the ideal generated by $\left\{ a_{i} \cdot \prod_{\substack{j=1 \\ j \ne i}}^{n} b_{j} \right\}$? And the isomorphism $M \rightarrow I$ is given by $x \mapsto \prod_{j=1}^{n} b_{j} \cdot x$?

Comment: @user100101212 yep that's right